# Highlight function does not work with vietnamese language

Tags: unicode, languages, soul

So i was trying to highlight some text in Vietnamese but all latex programs like overleaf and texstudio all failed to load the text. So what i did wrong? Here's my packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}

\hl{Cách thức} 

\end{document}
```

Should i change my way of using Vietnamese, because all the errors are utf-8 related or is there another reason? Thank you.

```
! Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets@combine has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 \hl{Cách thức}
                      
?
```

Comment: please provide an example and say what tex engine you are using, pdftex, xetex, luatex? (overleaf and texstudio are the editors you used but that does not affect the typesetting)

Comment: I guess it's just normal latex

Comment: I just use the utf8 not babel or any other packages

Comment: No it's not normal latex if it generates an error. Make a small one paragraph complete document that generates an error and show exactly the error message that you got copied from the log file to a code block in the question. Otherwise we have to guess what is wrong before guessing how to fix it.

Comment: I've got this: Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@two@octets@combine was complete. \item Phương pháp: \hl{Cách thức} and this Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets@combine has an extra }. \item Phương pháp: \hl{Cách thức} and this Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. \item Phương pháp: \hl{Cách thức} and this Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "A9. \item Phương pháp: \hl{Cách thức} and finally this Missing } inserted. \end{itemize}

Comment: I added the example this time:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The `soulutf8` package is an extension of `soul` that works with the utf-8 encoding mechanism used by pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color,soulutf8}


\begin{document}

\hl{Cách thức} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually works!